# Return a record despite a field being empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

(I'm new to Entity Framework, so apologies if this is an easy question!)

In my DB table, I have a column titled [SiteURL] and another [Keywords]

I have records in there, but some do not have any entries in the Keywords field.
I want to let my users filter the records based on these 2 columns.

My code is here:

```
Publishers = db.Publishers.Where(p =>
                      p.isActive == true
                  && p.SiteURL.ToLower().Contains(((txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.Length > 0) && (txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.ToLower() == "site url")) ? p.SiteURL.ToLower() : txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.ToLower())
                  && p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(((txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.Length > 0) && (txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.ToLower() == "keyword")) ? p.Keywords.ToLower() : txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.ToLower())
                    ).ToList();
```

I'm trying to say:

IF txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value isn't empty and doesn't equal "site url", Then Search [SiteURL] for whatever has been entered into txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value

AND

IF txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value isn't empty and doesn't equal "keyword", Then include [Keywords] in the criteria list for whatever has been entered into txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.

```
  ID  |  SiteURL  | Keywords  |
   1  |  Rod.org  | Travel    |
   2  |  jane.com |           |
   3  |  fred.com | motoring  |
```

So, if the user enters ".com" into txtFilterBy_SiteURL, I want to return

```
  ID  |  SiteURL  | Keywords  |
   2  |  jane.com |           |
   3  |  fred.com | motoring  |
```

If the user enters ".com" into txtFilterBy_SiteURL and "mot" into the txtFilterBy_KeyWord textbox, I want:

```
  ID  |  SiteURL  | Keywords  |
   3  |  fred.com | motoring  |
```

Comment: Isn't `p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(p.Keywords.ToLower())` always true??!!

Comment: Yes, I think I have over-simplified my example. The answers below are correct, but not giving me the records I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a bit of boolean logic where you fetch your publishers from database. The below is in LINQ to SQL but it should work as well. Apologize for the way the code below looks, couldn't get the long one-liners to display ok in here...

```
Publishers = (from p in db.Publishers
              where p.isActive == true &&
              p.SiteURL.ToLower().Contains(((txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.Length > 0) &&
                  (txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.ToLower() == "site url")) ?                   
                  p.SiteURL.ToLower() : txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Value.ToLower())  &&
              (p.Keywords == null || p.Keywords == "" ||  
                  p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(((txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.Length > 0)               
              &&   
              (txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.ToLower() == "keyword")) ?      
                  p.Keywords.ToLower() : txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Value.ToLower()))
              select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Publishers = db.Publishers.Where(p =>
             p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(p.Keywords.ToLower()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Keywords))
             ).ToList();
```

if KeyWords is a string.

Comment: You misplaced a parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Tony,  but I think I over-simplified my question.  I have edited it now to explain a little clearer my goal.

Answer (score 0):

this line always true for not null Keywords `p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(p.Keywords.ToLower())`

if  you need to filter check `null` before access Keywords property and then check `contains`

```
Publishers = db.Publishers.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Keywords) &&
             p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains("stringToSearch")
             ).ToList();
```

### Edit

```
// get all data
Publishers = db.Publishers.ToList();

// filter by site url 
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Text))
{
    Publishers = Publishers.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.SiteURL) &&
                 p.SiteURL.ToLower().Contains(txtFilterBy_SiteURL.Text)
                 ).ToList();
}
// filter by keyword 
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Text))
{
    Publishers = Publishers.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Keywords) &&
                 p.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(txtFilterBy_KeyWord.Text)
                 ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this returns the records without keywords, no matter what I search for.
 I think I have over-simplified my example, I will change my question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't need to return only the items with search text then use `&&` not `||` check my updated answer